# How to assist user to get Google Play Services

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-play-services

I have an app that uses Google Maps Android API v2 and therefore uses Google Play Services.

The problem I have is: How can I help those users that doesn't have Google Play Services installed?

I'm doing the usual check for the services:

```
int result = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

            switch (result) {
            case ConnectionResult.SUCCESS:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Map.class));                 
                break;
```

and if the result is no good I show a dialog with an option to the user:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage("Error mesage").setTitle("Error message title");

                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result, MainMenu.this, 32).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
```

When the user clickes "Yes" and are prompted with the Google Play Services the user clickes on that and are in the most cases forwarded to the Google Play store. But here there is another error message from Google Play saying something like "Unit (Phone) is not compatible with this version", which I think is odd because I'm using a HTC Sensation Z710e which I recently updated to 4.0.3 of android.

On my other phone HTC Wildfire S A510e with Android 2.3.5 nothing happens when the user clicks on the "Get Google Play Services" button from the `GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog`.

Any ideas what I can do to help the user get Google Play services?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try 2 things:

1.Debug and find out the value of **result** from isGooglePlayServicesAvailable method. In case of failure it should be one of these values:

```
SERVICE_MISSING, 
SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, 
SERVICE_DISABLED, 
SERVICE_INVALID
```

So you know why exactly the [Google Play services APK](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) is not available.

2.Note that Phone not compatible with this version - this message is sometimes shown to user when appropriate feature is not mentioned in uses-feature tag of android manifest.

Choose a correct feature from the [Feature Reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#features-reference) list for  in your manifest and take appropriate note of uses-sdk and permission tags.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have tried the first thing and I only get the "SERVICE_MISSING" when it fails. I have a <uses-feature> in my manifest that says "android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" could this have something to do with Google Play saying that its not the right version?

Comment: Turns out that the problem with the 4.0.3 version was that there was a error in the Google Play Store app. Had to restore the phone to factory settings to get it to work.